# If I re-sync the blockchain will I lose my coins and wallet address?

Tags: blockchain, daemon

I had a hard reset and now I'm getting the following error "Daemon fails to start."  Both with the GUI and command line.  The GUI still displays my coins and wallet name. Looks like I need to re sync with the blockchain. Before I do this I need to know whether I lose my coins and wallet address.  I have payouts coming from mining pools too so I need to keep my wallet address. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, you will not lose coins nor address.

The blockchain does not contain your keys. It's a copy of a distributed live data structure. Your wallet keys (from which your address is derived) are stored separately, and are used to scan the blockchain, but are not part of it. They're stored in the `<wallet-name>.keys` file (which can be recreated using the 25 word mnemonic seed which you carefully saved when you created the wallet).

But you might not need to resync the chain: maybe running monerod with `--db-salvage` will fix it. No guarantee, but it sometimes gets it back in a good state.